# create instance of two classes together

Tags: php, oop, class, pdo

Im trying to display two list: one for categories and brand but only the categories are being displayed. And when I remove the code for categories, the brands are being displayed. Is it because it is not possible to create instances of two classes in the same php page? 
In index.php:

```
 <?php 
 $obj = new CategoryList();
 if (method_exists($obj, 'init'))
 {  

     $obj->init();
 }
for($i = 0;$i< count($obj->mCategory); $i++)
{
    echo "<a href=''>";
    echo $obj->mCategory[$i]['name']. "<br/>";
    echo "</a>"; 
} 

$obj2 = new BrandList();
if (method_exists($obj2, 'init'))
{
  $obj2->init();
}
for($i = 0;$i< count($obj2->mBrand);$i++)
{
   echo "<a href=''>";
   echo $obj2->mBrand[$i]['name']. "<br/>";
   echo "</a>"; 
    }
 ?>
```

Here's the code for the classes:

$mSelectedCategory = (int)$_GET['category_id'];
        }


        public function init()
        {
            $this->mCategory = Catalog::GetCategory();

        }


    }

    ?>

```
<?php

class BrandList
{
    public $mSelectedBrand = 0;
    public $mBrand;


    public function __construct()
    {
        if (isset ($_GET['brand_id']))
            $this->$mSelectedBrand = (int)$_GET['brand_id'];
    }


    public function init()
    {
        $this->mBrand = Catalog::GetBrand();

    }


}

?>
```

Maybe this might help:

```
class Catalog
{
    //get id and name of category
    public static function GetCategory()
    {
        $sql = 'CALL catalog_get_category_list()';
        return DatabaseHandler::GetAll($sql);

    }

public static function GetBrand()
{
    $sql = 'CALL catalog_get_brands_list()';
    return DatabaseHandler::GetAll($sql);

}

}
```

in DatabaseHandler class:

```
 public static function GetAll($sqlQuery, $params = null, $fetchStyle = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
        {
            $result = null;
            try
            {
                $database_handler = self::GetHandler();
                $statement_handler = $database_handler->prepare($sqlQuery);
                $statement_handler->execute($params);
                $result = $statement_handler->fetchAll($fetchStyle);



            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                self::Close();
                trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);

            }
            return $result;
        }
```

Comment: If you're checking on the browser, look at the HTML source to see if the brands are actually being printed or not. If not, either your BrandList object is not being populated with entries, or there's an error, probably in the constructor or init() function.

Comment: Ive gone through the html source and only the categories are being printed..

Comment: `$this->$mSelectedBrand` - one $ too much, `$this->mSelectedBrand`. Did you redact the code for Stackoverflow or is this really an error?

Comment: It is actually an error.

Comment: Is the $pdo object GetHandler() returns set to raise exceptions in case of errors? Like e.g. `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. And do you have an eye on the error.log? (If you missed the warning for `$this->$mSelectedBrand` you probably also missed the E_USER_ERROR).

Comment: self::$_mHandler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); I had this line for error reporting but i removed it and replaced it by self::$_mHandler->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true); 
because I was getting an error: 
ERRNO: 256 TEXT: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). It was the only way to solve this problem

Comment: Keep the `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` line. Not seeing an error doesn't mean it's solved ;-) Which version of php do you use (win32/linux) ? Any chance of updating it to the latest version (5.3.1)?

Comment: I have recently updated to 5.3.1. I cant keep these two line together:
self::$_mHandler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
self::$_mHandler->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
Im getting the same error again:
ERRNO: 256
TEXT: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.

Comment: I actually solved the problem by replacing this line which calls the stored procedure : $sql = 'CALL catalog_get_category_list()'; 
by an SQL statement SELECT id,name from category;
Does that mean I wont be able to use stored procedures anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate dozens/hundreds/X of objects of any kind within the same php instance.
Use a debugger or add more debug (echo) code to find the error.

e.g. using this dummy implementation of the two classes

```
class CategoryList {
  public $mCategory=null;
  public function init() {
    $this->mCategory = array(
      array('name'=>'Cat A'),
      array('name'=>'Cat B'),
    );
  }
}

class BrandList {
  public $mBrand=null;
  public function init() {
    $this->mBrand = array(
      array('name'=>'Brand A'),
      array('name'=>'Brand B'),
    );
  }
}
```

your code prints

```
<a href=''>Cat A<br/></a><a href=''>Cat B<br/></a><a href=''>Brand A<br/></a><a href=''>Brand B<br/></a>
```

without any problem.

Comment: Yes, which means: you're barking up the wrong tree ;-) The code you initially posted isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: Ya you are right. Maybe there's is a problem with the way am getting the values from the other class. I have included the code for class Catalog

Answer (score 1):

No, you can create any number of instances even for the same class. Make sure that your both classes are included in your script independently of each other.

Comment: Thanks for your replies..There does not seem to be any error. and yes I have included both classes. But can anyone explain me why when I remove the codes for one list, the other list being displayed? Ive tried so many ways..but can't find a solution to this

Comment: Without seeing the code for both classes it's pure speculation.